# Weird lines inside window when property SizeToContent is set

Tags: wpf, xaml, sizetocontent

When I set the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` property in my window, WPF renders weird lines around my window:

[image: A custom message box with grey lines at the bottom and partially on the right edge of the window.]

Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These artifacts sometimes appear due to sizes not fitting pixel boundaries. You can mitigate the effects by setting [`UseLayoutRounding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to `true` on root elements or alternatively setting [`SnapsToDevicePixels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to child controls. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks):

> When the `UseLayoutRounding` property for an element is `true`, all non-integral pixel values that are calculated during the `Measure` and `Arrange` passes are rounded to whole pixel values. [...] Drawing objects on pixel boundaries eliminates the semi-transparent edges that are produced by anti-aliasing, when an edge falls in the middle of a device pixel.

In your code, you can set it to the root `Window` like this:

```
<Window ...
        UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

Please note, that `UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels` are not exactly the same. Choose what fits your requirements best. Here is a source for further reading on the latter:

- [Pixel Snapping in WPF Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa970908(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)